# ImageView does not align properly

Tags: android, xml

I have the following design where I want my left user image and then textviews on the right of the user image and arrow image on the right-most. However, for some reasons, arrow does not come to the right-most

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="6dip"
  android:background="#FFFFFF">
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/userimage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dip">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Username_05"
        android:singleLine="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondline"
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_below="@id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:singleLine="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my current output:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Update 1:

[image]

Comment: change <code>layout_width</code> to <code>wrap_content</code> BTW<code>single_line</code> is deprecated use <code>max_lines</code> = 1

Comment: fill_parent is also deprecated; use match_parent instead

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple. Use LinearLayout with horizontally orientation instead of RelativeLayout and add
1. ImageView
2. Another LinearLayout with layout_weight=1 and vertical orientation which will contain the two TextViews
3. ImageView

Sorry for not posting any code. I'm from mobile ;)

Comment: I have updated my question based on your approach. The only issue is right image does not come to the right most.

Comment: On the second LinearLayout, the one with the TextViews add android:layout_weight=1

Comment: I did, it is still same

Comment: just add android:layout_weight="1" in the nested linear layout

Comment: once I add, textviews disappear

Comment: width must be either match parent or 0dp. Can't tell for sure which one. Try them both.

Comment: add android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" in the nested linear layout, and android:layout_width="wrap_content" in the right image, but is recommended to use RelativeLayout instead of nested layouts

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you use android:layout_width="match_parent" instead of wrap content.

If you use linear Layout, you need a weight to use all the space:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="6dip"
          android:background="#FFFFFF">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/userimage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="6dip">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Username_05"
        android:singleLine="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondline"
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_below="@id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</LinearLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Inside the two textview, in the second you use fill_parent (it is the same as match_parent)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this

[image]

. There is no point creating a separate Imageview to accomodate the icons.
Better use the `android:drawableLeft` and `android:drawableRight` to achieve that.

Below is the sample code:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:text="Testing"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_24dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_24dp"/>
```

**Edit:**
For multiline :

[image]

Comment: Yes it is quite similar. I only need two text lines rather than one.

Comment: If you use `android:text="Testing\n Part1"` , you will get Part1 in the new line. You can always concat two strings and add a new line in between them. Just saying.

Comment: The first line -textview will be bold, but the second one not. How would you handle?

Answer (score 1):

First, do not use `android:orientation` on a `RelativeLayout`, that property is only for `LinearLayout`.

Second, you are doing circular references:

- Username has `android:layout_above="@id/secondline"`
- SecondLine has `android:layout_below="@id/username"`

When you do that the system does not know how to render the views, because they depend on each other.

Try doing this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="6dip"
                android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/userimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Username_05"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/userimage"
        android:singleLine="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondline"
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_below="@id/username"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/userimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It gave me the same result. no difference is observed.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you want. This matches the description that you posted, do a sync before installing the app with these changes

Comment: I posted the result

Comment: Unfortunately, even though I directly copied from the your code, I am getting different. I only added image src, nothing is changed.

Comment: In the design, I could able to see preview.

Comment: It is not reloading your layout, you should check this on a device and will see that it works

Comment: In the designer, it looks correct. But when I run it, I dont see arrow. I am using activity as a dialog.

Comment: I updated the code, try using `wrap_content` in TextViews

Answer (score 1):

Just use layout_weight.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="6dip">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/userimage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:layout_weight=".1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_my_calendar" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Username_05"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/username"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: In the designer, it looks correct. But when I run it, I dont see arrow. I am using activity as a dialog.

Comment: Can you post out the image of dialog ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the code you provided in your question but change `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to  `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` in the `ImageView` of your arrow.
This should make the arrow `ImageView` appear at the complete right